# How do I prove two spans are equal in this scenario?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

[image]

How would I formulate a proof in this scenario? All I know is that Span(X1...Xn) = Span(t1X1...tnXn). Could anyone help me get into the right direction?

Comment: Please don't post unsearchable pictures of equations.  Instead typeset using *MathJax*.

Comment: All you need to do is show that each element of one spanning set belongs to the span of the other. For example, $X - 2Y$ belongs to the span of $\{X, Y\}$, because it is literally a linear combination of $X$ and $Y$. In fact, this applies to all of the vectors on the right hand side are, and linear combinations of these linear combinations of $X$ and $Y$ will also be linear combinations of $X$ and $Y$. So, we have $\subseteq$ at least. Now, what about the reverse direction? Can you write $X$ and $Y$ as linear combinations of $X-2Y,2X+Y,X-Y,5Y$?

Comment: So in the instance of X-2Y, X=2Y?

Comment: @James No, I'm not suggesting $X - 2Y = 0$. It's just a vector, like $X$ and $Y$. It belongs in the span of $\{X, Y\}$, because it takes the form $aX + bY$ ($a = 1$ and $b = -2$ here). Are you following me so far?

Comment: Oh ok, I get it now. So I just go through all of them for the proof I bet?

Comment: @James Well, going through all the vectors on the right will establish that $\operatorname{span}\{X,Y\}\subseteq\operatorname{span}\{X-2Y,2X+Y,X-Y,5Y\}$. That's sort of the easy direction. The question is, can you write $X$ and $Y$ as linear combinations of the four vectors on the right? For example, can you find $a, b, c, d$ such that $Y = a(X - 2Y) + b(2X + Y) + c(X - Y) + d(5Y)$?

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

$$ (X-2Y)+2(2X+Y) = 5X$$
$$ \frac{1}{5}(5Y) = Y$$